# Implementation Google Pay into the Xamarin.Android with the MvvmCross 6.0

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-pay

In the previous version of MvvmCross (5.7) used the following Navigation:

```
ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>(myNavigation);
```

The transition was carried out, the View (SecondView) was drawn, everything was normal. But after MvvmCross update to version 6  navigation was replaced to:

```
_navigationService.Navigate< SecondViewModel, options, DestructionResult<settings>>(new params { navigation = myNavigation });
```

And in the usual case everything works fine, but if you run the transition from the GooglePayFragment:

```
SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
.Add(Resource.Id.dynamic_wallet_fragment, _selectionWalletFragment)
.Commit();
```

After processing the received Intent:

```
private void DoAndroidPay(Intent data)
{
    mFullWallet = data.GetParcelableExtra (WalletConstants.ExtraFullWallet).JavaCast<FullWallet>();
    var token = mFullWallet.PaymentMethodToken;
    ViewModel.DoPayWithAndroidPay (token.Token);
}

public void DoPayWithAndroidPay(string paymentTokenJson)
{
   _navigationService.Navigate< SecondViewModel, Params, DestructionResult<Params>>(new Params { token = paymentTokenJson });
}
```

the transition is performed, the logic works, but the View of SecondViewModel is not drawn. If SecondViewModel contains a transition to SomeViewModel, it is performed normally (SomeView is rendered).

Temporarily solved the problem by substituting a blank page, which takes you to SecondViewModel.

```
public class TemporaryPayViewModel : LoadingViewModel<Params, DestructionResult<Params>>
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public override void Prepare(Params parameter)
        {
            Initialize (parameter.token);
        }
    private async void Initialize(string paymentTokenJson)
        {
            if (!await GetPaymentFormUrl(paymentTokenJson))
                return;
            await _navigationService.Navigate< SecondViewModel, Params, DestructionResult<Params>>(new Params { token = paymentTokenJson });
        }
}
```

How to remove this workaround, and make the second screen (SecondViewModel) would be drawn after pressing pay in the fragment from GooglePay (Android.Gms.Wallet.Fragment)?